# C# Casting oddity

Tags: c#, casting

I'm playing around with generics in a weird circumstance and I've come across a weird situation whose "solution" I don't expect to work.  Here's the offending code...

```
static TournamentGame<T, Y> make16Game<T, Y>(int gameId, int seed1, int seed2, List<Y> teams)
        where T : TournamentTeam<Y>
        where Y : Team
    {
        /*
         * bunch of code removed for clarity
         */

        // return that bad boy
        return new TournamentGame<T, Y>(gameId,
                                        (T)(new TournamentTeam<Y>(seed1, teams[seed1 - 1])),
                                        (T)(new TournamentTeam<Y>(seed2, teams[seed2 - 1])));
    }
```

Looking at this, I don't see how the compiler allows this.  My intuition is that I'll get a runtime error if I ever invoke this with a `T` other than `TournamentTeam`.  If I don't put in the cast, I get a compile error.  Is my intuition on this correct?  What I'd LOVE to do is enforce a constraint that `T` must have a constructor that takes a `String` and a `Y` parameter, but that's another issue.  I suppose I could also use reflection to get that constructor for `T`, but where's the fun in that?

Anyway, thoughts?

EDIT
The `TournamentGame` looks like the following:

```
public class TournamentGame<T, Y> : Game<T>
    where T : TournamentTeam<Y>
    where Y : Team
{
    public TournamentGame(int id, T t1, T t2, Region<T, Y> region = null)
        : base(id, t1, t2)
    { 
        // do your thang
    }
}

public class Game<T>
    where T : Team
{
    private T mTeam1 = null;

    private Game(int id)
    {
        // do your thang
    }

    public Game(int id, T t1, T t2)
        : this(id)
    {
        // do your thang
    }

    public T Team1
    {
        get 
        {
            // do your thang
        }
    }
 }
```

Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but I see nothing generic in this method, just a really awkward way of using regular types.\

Comment: well, much of the reason for my using generics is hidden from this code example because the generics come in to play in the object types being used, not in this specific code.  This function is a helper function for another static function that does require generics.  I'm more asking about the cast in the return statement, though, and if that is a good or bad idea.

Comment: You are correct, though.  this question has nothing to do with generics, and I realized that before I hit the submit button and actually changed the title, but forgot to remove the generics tag.  Removing that tag now.

Comment: Do you _really_ need `T`?  Why not replace all references of `T` with `TournamentTeam<Y>`?

Comment: Well, if I never want to extend off of `TournamentTeam<>`, then I can get away with that.  Would making such an assumption be a good coding practice, though?  If I made that assumption and changed my code accordingly, then if I ever _do_ extend off of it, then not only do I have to change `TournamentGame`, I've also got to change every class that uses it.

Comment: I've actually got another question that deals with why I need the `T` though.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652693/what-design-pattern-would-this-be-and-is-it-a-good-idea-c).  Sorry for the double-post, if that's frowned upon here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with your code (more or less) and resharper immediately told me that the cast to T was unnecessary:

```
public class Test
{
    static TournamentGame<T, Y> make16Game<T, Y>(int gameId, int seed1, int seed2, List<Y> teams)
        where T : TournamentTeam<Y>
        where Y : Team
    {
        return new TournamentGame<T, Y>(gameId, 
                                        new TournamentTeam<Y>(seed1, teams[seed1 - 1]),
                                        new TournamentTeam<Y>(seed2, teams[seed2 - 1]));
    }
}

internal class Team { }

internal class TournamentTeam<T> {
    public TournamentTeam(int seed1, Team team) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

internal class TournamentGame<T, Y> {
    public TournamentGame(int gameId, TournamentTeam<Y> tournamentTeam, TournamentTeam<Y> tournamentTeam1) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So the need for the cast to T is coming from somewhere else. If you want a specific type of "constructor" for T, you can always pass along a factory method:

```
    static TournamentGame<T, Y> make16Game<T, Y>(int gameId, int seed1, int seed2, Func<int, Y, T> tournamentTeamFactory, List<Y> teams)
        where T : TournamentTeam<Y>
        where Y : Team
    {
        return new TournamentGame<T, Y>(gameId, 
            tournamentTeamFactory(seed1, teams[seed1 - 1]), 
            tournamentTeamFactory(seed2, teams[seed2 - 1]));
    }
```

EDIT: Given the constructor code that you are using, it is clear why you need a cast to T (and why passing along a factory method, as I suggest above, is a good idea).  If you want to limit TournamentGame to only taking TournamentTeams (which your code is *effectively* doing) then provide a constructor that takes TournamentTeam directly.  If not, then you shouldn't be creating TournamentTeams in your make16Game function. Imagine the following:

```
public class AllStarTeam<T> : TournamentTeam<T> where T : Team
{
    public AllStarTeam(int seed1, Team team) : base(seed1, team)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then this compiles, but throws a run time exception (a Bad Thing):

```
Test.make16Game<AllStarTeam<T>, T>(5, 5, 5, new List<T>());
```

Comment: That's odd that it would say the cast isn't necessary. VS2010 on 4.0 gives a "cannot convert from TournamentTeam<Y> to T" error, which would make sense.  What if I passed in a "B" type for the method that extends off of TournamentTeam<Y>?  When I tried to then cast a TournamentTeam<Y> object into a B, I should get an InvalidCastException, or so I would expect.

Comment: The first code example I posted does compile with VS2010 on 4.0 for me. Perhaps the constructor for your `TournamentGame` class is different?  You didn't post that part.

Comment: See my edit- you really do need a cast if you are going to do it that way.

Comment: Regarding the edit, you are certainly right that a factory object is called for.  What I'm curious about is why is the compiler even allowing that cast?  It only works in one case, and that is when `T` is `TournamentTeam<Y>`.  Am I correct that when I call this with something other than that, I'll get an exception?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you can't specify such constraints on constructor in generics. [Here is some thoughts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) related to your question.

Comment: Interesting read.  He does seem to be mulling over the same issues I've been dealing with.